# Http PUT in Angular2 to .NET Core Web API gives http 401 error from the preflight request

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular2 app which does an http PUT to a .NET Core Web API controller. When I run the app, it makes an OPTIONS preflight request first and throws a 401 Unauthorized error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:55137/api/Foo/2. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

I've tried doing the PUT directly from Postman and it works fine. Don't know if this is relevant, but my GETs from the Angular app are working fine too. I've put together the following code with some help from documentation and searching around the web, but I'm not understanding fully enough to know why the OPTIONS pre-flight request is unauthorized? I've tried a few things like removing and re-adding the OPTIONSVerbHandler in the web.config. I've also read that the preflight request requires that you DON'T send credentials, but I'm not sure how to do that in my case.

I'm using Angular 2.0.0-rc.5 and .NET Core 1.0.0, and hosting on IIS 8.5 (IISExpress while developing in Visual Studio 2015).

**foo.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { CONFIG } from "./../app.config";

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
    private _apiUrl: string = CONFIG.generalAPI;
    private _headers: Headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    updateObj(fooObj: any): Promise<any> {
        let body: any = JSON.stringify(fooObj);
        let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            headers: this._headers,
            withCredentials: true
        });
        let result: Promise<any> = this.http.put(this._apiUrl + "/Foo/" + fooObj.ID, body, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
        return result;
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error("An error occurred", error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**fooController.cs:**

```
// PUT api/Foo/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]FooClass obj)
{
    try
    {
        _fooService.UpdateFoo(obj);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest("An error occurred. Message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**web.config for the webAPI app:**

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:44612" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
</customHeaders>
```

Comment: I've only done it in ASP .NET MVC by using the [EnableCors()] attribute and I don't know if that's going to work for your framework, but I do know that trying to fake it with custom headers isn't the intended approach.

Comment: How are you using `web.config` if you're using `.NET Core 1.0.0`?

Comment: You still use web.config if you host under IIS or IISExpress.

Comment: Are you sure it's loading properly?  You can do the same in middleware.

Comment: Do you have `Authorize` attribute on the webapi controller. If yes, it may be expecting `Authorization` header in the request coming from Angular. But as per your code you are passing only `content-type` header.

Comment: @Brad Tried middleware when I first started the project and ran into some issues so I went to configuring CORS in web.config. Tried going back to middleware and got it to work this time.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of web.config, can you enable CORS like this in your ASP.NET core web api-

First, add dependency in project.json - `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",`

then enable CORS in `startup.cs` like this-

```
app.UseCors(builder => {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
});
```

In case if you want to restrict to specific origin then you can do like this-

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("example.com"));
```

You can find more information about CORS [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html)

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment I had tried enabling CORS in middleware but ran into some other issues, so resorted to enabling it in web.config. Went back to this route and got it to work this time. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: Here's the code I used to specify the specific origin, headers and methods: `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:XXXX").WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").WithHeaders("Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization").AllowCredentials();`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an HttpPut with no body.
If you don't send a body (even a null or something like that) the API will return Unauthorized.

```js
const url = `${this.apiEndPoints.kycCasesEndPoint}/${clientId}/assign`;
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  this.authService.authToken);
return this.http.put<KycCaseAssign>(url, null, { headers })
```